# Create table with NULL timestamp columns in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

```
`effective_end_utc` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'The UTC timestamp for when the target ceases to be in effect.',
```

This will end up giving me

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 27: Invalid default value for 'effective_end_utc'
```

Base on other reponse, I have even set the mode to following at the begining of schema

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'
```

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: remove this from the query: COMMENT 'The UTC timestamp for when the target ceases to be in effect.' just use `effective_end_utc` timestamp NOT NULL

Comment: we use comments in every line. It does not change anything.

Comment: can you provide complete query

Comment: Look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545124/error-1067-42000-invalid-default-value-for-end-time). And by the way, `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` only applies to date(-time), not to timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema should be changed with a default value like

```
 `reported_timestamp_utc` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT
```